# Como por um JScrollPane em um JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Estou tentando criar um projeto onde imprimo diversas frases em um `JTextArea`, mas para isso, preciso incluir um `JScrollPane`. Olhei alguns exemplos na internet mas nenhum está funcionando.

```
public class Projeto extends JFrame {

    JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    public static JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
    public static JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
    JButton cmd1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Projeto();
}

public Projeto(){
    super("Árvore");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    painel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    painel.setLayout(null);

    cmd1 = new JButton("Start!");
    cmd1.setBounds(450, 50, 100, 30);
    painel.add(cmd1);

    textarea.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
    textarea.setEditable(true);
    sp.add(textarea);

    painel.add(sp);       

    add(painel);
    pack();

    setVisible(true);

    event e = new event();
    cmd1.addActionListener(e);            
}

public static void atualiza(String frase){
    textarea.append(frase);
}   

public class event implements ActionListener{
    Pai p = new Pai();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        p.start();                       
    }          
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina a `JTextArea` como `portview` do `JScrollPane`:

```
sp.setViewportView(textarea);
```

Um `JScrollPane` é um container flexível, que se adapta conforme um componente adicionado a ele. Mas para isso, este componente precisa ser um *viewPort* do painel rolável. Isso só é possível passando o componente para o painel em seu construtor ao inicia-lo, ou utilizando o método [`setViewportView()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView-java.awt.Component-). O método `add` não funciona corretamente para este painel em especifico.

---

Uma dica:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, vai ter que posicionar todos manualmente.

No seu código mesmo, por utilizar layout absoluto, a `JTextArea` jamais será exibida, pois você definiu um tamanho e posição pra ele, mas para o scrollpane não há nada sobre seu tamanho e posição. Com a alteração abaixo, o componente é exibido normalmente:

```
sp.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
textarea.setEditable(true);
sp.setViewportView(textarea);
```

Comment: O problema é que eu uso o painel.add(sp); mas o JScrollPane e o JTextArea não estão mais aparecendo no painel.

Comment: @GustavoCruz você alterou conforme a resposta? Isso parece ser outro problema diferente.

Comment: Alterei sim e continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @GustavoCruz o problema não tem a ver com isso, é que você está usando layout absoluto, o que é uma pessima pratica. Pesquise sobre layouts managers para swing, layout absoluto só causa esse tipo de problema, ainda mais se não souber exatamente o que se está fazendo com ele.

Comment: @GustavoCruz mas se quiser continuar utilizando layout absoluto, veja a edição.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido. Muito obrigado pela ajuda Articuno.